# Replace image property in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, image, rotation, windows-phone-8.1

I´m rotating an image from the library in my app. The image has a rotation Clockwise270Degress so I rotate it 90 more to get it in Normal rotation. When I´ve done this, the image property System.Photo.Orientation still have a rotation which means the image will be viewed with wrong rotation in library when I save it there. So I need to replace the old System.Photo.Orientation but when I try to make the call below I get "value does not fall within the expected range."

```
await imageStorageFile.Properties.SavePropertiesAsync(new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>() { new KeyValuePair<string, object>("System.Photo.Orientation", (ushort)PhotoOrientation.Normal) });
```

I suspects that the old value has to be deleted but there is no delete method. How can I replace the value?

Comment: ushort comes from debug the current value. I´ve also tested uint and int without success